# Use glob matching, when passing files to browserify in gulp

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gulp, browserify

All the examples I have seen using browserify and gulp assume that you only want to browserify 1 file.  This is usually not the case.

I came across an example that used vinyl-transforms, but I am unable to get it to work correctly.  Here is the (coffee-script) code:

```
# Browserify JS

gulp.task 'browserify', [], ->

    # Create the transform
    br = transform (f) ->
        return browserify(f).bundle()

    # Run browserify
    gulp.src(['./public/js/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(br)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
```

But I get the following error:

```
[10:50:55] Starting 'browserify'...

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: write after end
```

Comment: You typically use one file as the entry point, then browserify builds the dependency graph and adds all the necessary files. Do you have an entire directory of browserify entry points?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple entrypoints for browserify

Comment: consider using `require-globify`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `glob` directly:

```
var glob = require('glob');

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
  var files = glob.sync('./public/js/**/*.js');
  return browserify({entries: files})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

Comment: So simple, cant believe it took me so long to find this!  Thanks

Comment: it seems that passing an array to glob.sync is no longer valid, I tried but got ```Type Error: glob pattern string required```. Passing a string worked  fine. Thanks for the answer by the way!

Comment: use `glob-array` if you want to pass an array